# Why is my Flutter package suddenly warning me that it doesn't depend on its example app?

Tags: dart, package, flutter

I'm doing `flutter packages pub publish --dry-run` to publish an update to my package, GroovinMaterialIcons, and I'm getting warnings that it doesn't depend on the example app:

```
Suggestions:
* line 3, column 1 of example\lib\main.dart: This package doesn't depend on groovin_material_icons_testapp.
  import 'package:groovin_material_icons_testapp/icon_map.dart';
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
* line 4, column 1 of example\lib\main.dart: This package doesn't depend on groovin_material_icons_testapp.
  import 'package:groovin_material_icons_testapp/search.dart';
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
* line 3, column 1 of example\lib\search.dart: This package doesn't depend on groovin_material_icons_testapp.
  import 'package:groovin_material_icons_testapp/icon_map.dart';
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This has never happened to me before. Why would the package need to depend on the example?

Comment: I assume this is caused by improved checks in an update to the Dart `pub` tool used by Flutter.

Comment: Do you have `groovin_material_icons_testapp` in `dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml`? Actually I don't understand how the suggestion and the import lines with the squiggled line might be related. I think we need more information about your project.

Comment: It will probably affect the health. I don't know what you can do. You might know more about where `groovin_material_icons_testapp groovin_material_icons_testapp` comes from. These names don't mean anything to me.

Comment: No, I do not have it as a dependency. You can view the project here: https://github.com/GroovinChip/groovin_material_icons

Comment: I guess it's because of the `pubspec.yaml` file in `example/...`. I think the rules have tightened here. Try to move all files from `example/...` to `example/example1/...` (where `example1` can be any directory name)

Comment: Moving to the new directory structure as you suggest results in the entire example becoming riddled with errors

Comment: You would need to change `groovin_material_icons:
    path: ..` to `groovin_material_icons:
    path: ../..` in  `example/example1/pubspec.yaml`

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart/issues/1434 is somewhat related. I haven't found a proper documentation about how the `example/` content should be structured. There is https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout#examples but that doesn't cover your use case either.

Comment: The example builds, but when I do the packages dry run I still get the errors I got from the start

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10001 but that should be fixed since months. Are you using a recent Flutter version?

Comment: Ah not on this particular machine, it was still on 0.6.0. Upgrading now, will update.

Comment: Updated to latest Flutter and still having the same errors

Comment: I'd create a bug report in github.com/dart-lang/pub and ignore the warning for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by specifying relative path instead of using `package:*` syntax. E.g. This one gave me warning

```
import 'package:example/main.dart
```

which was fixed when I replaced it with

```
import '../lib/main.dart'
```

I know that's not the recommended way but the warning went away after this.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably run the dart file with the dart icon instead of the Flutter icon try to run with the Flutter icon.